# Delete object handle and keep variable in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Using the `delete` function, I can delete the object handle but it also removes the object properties from the variable.
Is there a way to delete the object handle without touching to the variable properties?

For example, I have two plots like below and I delete the first one.

```
figure;
h1 = plot( 1:10, '*' );
hold on
h2 = plot( 2:5, '.' );
delete( h1 );
h1.XData % returns an error, handle has been removed
```

The `h1` object handle has been removed from the figure as expected but all the `h1` properties (`XData`, `YData`) also have been removed. Is there a way to keep the `h1` properties? Do I necessarily need to back up the properties before using `delete`?

Comment: YES. You need to back up anything you want to keep from a graphic object before you delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of deleting `h1`, simply hide it:

```
h1.Visible = 'off';
```

And you can see the data is still there:

```
>> h1.XData
ans =
     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10
```