# Keep data from figures MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I would like to keep data from figures using gcf. However, when I close the figure, I lose all the data stored into my variable.

```
map = randn(10,10);
figure; imagesc(map);
fig = gcf; % I have the data stored into fig
close all;
fig; % Error : handle to deleted Figure
```

How can I keep data from gcf even if the figure is closed.

Comment: What do you expect to retain in `fig` after the figure is closed? You already have all the plot data within `map`, all other properties are obsolete/lost because they pertain to an object you've deleted by closing it...

Comment: Because I want to access to all the parameters such as axis, colorbar, title, ...

Comment: Then you need to store those attributes in a struct or individual variables before you close the figure. Once you close the figure, it no longer exists and you're asking what the title of _nothing_ is

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44794877/delete-object-handle-and-keep-variable-in-matlab

Answer (score 1):

You could save your figure as file using `saveas` before closing it.
When you need it again, you can reload it with `open`.

Full example:

```
map = randn(10,10);
figure; imagesc(map);
fig = gcf;

%% Save figure in file 'MyFigureFile.fig'
saveas( fig, 'MyFigureFile', 'fig') 

close all;

%% Load figure from file 'MyFigureFile.fig'
open( 'MyFigureFile.fig' );
```

---

*Other Option:*

You could simply hide the figure instead of closing it using  `fig.Visible = false` or `fig.Visible = 'off'`  as suggested in [Delete object handle and keep variable in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44794877/delete-object-handle-and-keep-variable-in-matlab).